# Extract id field as key django rest framework serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Say I have a Blog model which has the following fields:
`id` `content` `title`

If I am to create a model serializer, It would serialize to this:

```
[
   {id: 1, content: "content1", title: "title1"},
   {id: 2, content: "content2", title: "title2"},
]
```

But I want it to serialize to this:

```
{
   '1': {content: "content1", title: "title1"},
   '2': {content: "content2", title: "title2"},
}
```

This way, I could access elements faster on the front end given their id instead of having to search for the id manually.
How can I do that ?

**Edit :**
Overriding to_representation as @ArshDoda said in the comments worked. but now It serializes to this:

```
[
   {
      "1": {content: "content1", title: "title1"}
   },
   {
      "2": {content: "content2", title: "title2"}
   },
]
```

That's pretty much the same problem. I can't immediately access them on the frontend because it's an array. I want it to be an object of all the blogs not an array just like the one above. I think the reason It becomes an array, is when I create the serializer, I use `many=True` like this: `blog_serializer = BlogSerializer(data, many=True)`. How do I solve that ?

**Edit 2:**
Here is the code of to_representation :

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    my_id = ret['id']
    del ret['id']
    return {my_id: ret}
```

Comment: Use to_representation function in the serializer to customize the output

Comment: Can you please elaborate or provide any resources ?

Comment: Checkot the basic example: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5682/files

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and see

Comment: why you want to get second way? for front end it does not matter list or map, front in any way will do for loop, but making key id it's more elegant and right

Comment: In the front end, I have a select input which is prefilled with blogs titles and when user selects a blog, I view it. Instead of searching for the blog by id, I want to access it immediately.

Comment: @ArshDoda Thank you very much, It worked. but there is a little problem, See my edit

Comment: Can you share the to_representation code

Comment: Haven't try this but you can also override to_representation in the [ListSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) to change the behavior when many=True

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was by overriding the list() method in your viewset:

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # Override list method to list the data as a dictionary instead of array
        response = super(BlogViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)  # Call the original 'list'
        response_dict = {}
        for item in response.data:
            idKey = item.pop('id')  # Remove id from list to use it as key instead
            response_dict[idKey] = item
        response.data = response_dict  # Customize response data into dictionary with id as keys instead of using array
        return response  # Return response with this custom representation
```